# 3D projection, Similar to SceneCapture2D

Tags: game-design, rendering, unreal-4, projection

I would appreciate some help, I was wondering if it was possible in UE4 to do a "3D projection" of a scene, Similar to what SceneCapture2D does, but the viewer can see a 3D scene (with a character inside).

[image]

In this image is SceneCapture2D, the character is in the far left room.

[image]

This is the idea, but its a live 3D projection.

Comment: Note that the pixels you put on the player's screen are still 2D, so you should be able to do this with a SceneCapture2D, just with a tilted display plane and carefully-matched camera frustum.